# Can I completely replace xterm with emacs' term mode?

Tags: term

What short comings can I expect from this mode, and what are some use cases for which I should really prefer my operating system's terminal emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `ansi-term` almost exclusively, so I would say "almost".

Speed is your main concern -- anything which rapidly generates large amounts of output is going to cause some pain, as Emacs won't keep up with it. If I know I'm about to issue such a shell command, I pull up a dedicated terminal emulator.

If you're using Emacs 24 then https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints#bidi can cause awful slow-downs in certain situations.

Emacs commands can potentially put the buffer in an inconsistent state, which is confusing at best. You might find https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17086 helpful.

Comment: This one is a bit tangential, but if you're making regular use of `term` then you may also find the following idea useful as well: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18678

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview) is a helpful overview of ways to use the various shells and terminals in emacs. I use eshell for most things (here's [my config for eshell](https://github.com/mclear-tools/dotemacs/blob/master/config.org#eshell)) if you care to take a look. But as the other answer notes, if you're going to be dumping a lot of text in a terminal, emacs will likely be too slow.