# ansi-term changes in line-mode not registered after char-mode

Tags: shell, ansi-term, term, bash

Here's the situation. I start `M-x ansi-term`, which launches it in `term-char-mode`. I type the following:

```
echo "hello world"
```

and press RET, which outputs on the next line the expected output `hello world`. Now I press `C-p` which brings up the previous statement that I just typed (`echo "hello world"` in this example) and I place the cursor with repeated `C-b` just before the word `world` (in other words before `w`). Now I do `M-x term-line-mode` and I do some edits to the command. **Weird stuff happens at this point**. Sometimes the edits are not registered after I go back to `M-x term-char-mode` and execute the edited command, sometimes the text jumbles, etc. A screencast shows these possibilities: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVGxk.jpg.

Here is my setup in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` related to `ansi-term`:

```
;;;;;; Improving ansi-term
;; make that C-c t e launches an ansi-term buffer in the current window
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t e") 'ansi-term)
;; avoid ansi-term asking always which shell to run (always run bash)
(defvar my-term-shell "/bin/bash")
(defadvice ansi-term (before force-bash)
  (interactive (list my-term-shell)))
(ad-activate 'ansi-term)
;; display of certain characters and control codes to UTF-8
(defun my-term-use-utf8 ()
  (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix))
(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'my-term-use-utf8)
;; clickable URLs
(defun my-term-hook ()
  (goto-address-mode))
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'my-term-hook)
;; make that typing exit in ansi-term (which exits the shell) also
;; closes the buffer
(defadvice term-sentinel (around my-advice-term-sentinel (proc msg))
  (if (memq (process-status proc) '(signal exit))
      (let ((buffer (process-buffer proc)))
        ad-do-it
        (kill-buffer buffer))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'term-sentinel)
;; fix the problem of moving cursor left/right being captured by emacs
;; instead of underlying terminal, leading to jumbling when jumping
;; words then editing the middle of a command. Same for deleting
;; backward/forward whole words.
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(progn
     ;; rename buffer
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c r") 'rename-buffer)

     ;; make sure typical key combos work in term-char-mode
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'nil)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-&") 'nil)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-!") 'nil)

     ;; make sure C-c t e launches a new ansi-term buffer when current
     ;; buffer is also ansi-term
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c t e") 'nil)

     ;; move by whole words fix
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<right>") 'term-send-Cright)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<left>") 'term-send-Cleft)
     (defun term-send-Cright () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5C"))
     (defun term-send-Cleft  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5D"))
     (defun term-send-Mbackspace () (interactive)(term-send-raw-string "\e\d"))

     ;; word deletion fix
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-w") 'term-send-Mbackspace)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-<backspace>") 'term-send-Mbackspace)     

     ;; switch between char and line mode with logical keystrokes
     (add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c t c") 'term-char-mode)))
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c t l") 'term-line-mode)

     ;; copy/paste native Emacs keystrokes
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-k") 'term-send-raw)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'term-paste)

     ;; ensure that scrolling doesn't break on output
     ;;(setq term-scroll-show-maximum-output t)
     (setq term-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)

     ;; max history (# lines) to keep (0 == keep everything)
     (setq term-buffer-maximum-size 50000)))
;; ansi-term bi-directional text support problem fix, which seems to
;; be the cause of text jumbling when going back commands in
;; ansi-term. This fixes it, yay!
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'my-term-mode-hook)
(defun my-term-mode-hook ()
  ;; https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20611
  (setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'left-to-right))
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Related Q&A: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17085/undesirable-cursor-jump-after-movement-with-m-left-or-m-right-in-term-mode