# utf-8 characters with eshell, eshell-visual-subcommands, and git

Tags: eshell, git, term, utf-8

Using the configuration

```el
(eval-after-load "em-term"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'eshell-visual-subcommands '("git" "diff" "help" "log" "show"))
     (add-to-list 'eshell-visual-options '("git" "--help" "--paginate"))))
```

eshell opens `git help diff` in a `term-mode` buffer. The buffer file coding system of this buffer is set to utf-8.

Even so utf-8 characters in the output of `git help diff` are shown as octal codes (see `doesn't` in the last line):

```
--full-diff
    Without this flag, git log -p <path>...  shows commits that touch the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths. With this, the full diff is shown for commits that touch the
    specified paths; this means that "<path>..." limits only commits, and doesn\342\200\231t limit diff for those commits.
```

I assume that the problem is connected to the following section of the function `term-exec-1`:

```el
;; The process's output contains not just chars but also binary
;; escape codes, so we need to see the raw output.  We will have to
;; do the decoding by hand on the parts that are made of chars.
(coding-system-for-read 'binary)
```

Is there a workaround?

I 've tried the method described in ["Unicode characters in emacs term-mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820051/unicode-characters-in-emacs-term-mode). They don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the lines

```el
;; display of certain characters and control codes to UTF-8
(defun my-term-use-utf8 ()
  (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix))
(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'my-term-use-utf8)
```

in the `ansi-term` configuration of user [space_voyager](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/13661/space-voyager) in his question ["ansi-term changes in line-mode not registered after char-mode"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/ansi-term-changes-in-line-mode-not-registered-after-char-mode).

These lines work for me (emacs 25.2.1 on cygwin).